# Excel VBA automated Data from web .aspx

Tags: vba, excel

I am trying to automate the process of data collection from the following [website](http://www.pflegelotse.de/).

I failed already at the first task, which is clicking the buttons and submitting a postal code.

1. The first part of the code should click the left button **Pflegeeinrichtungen und Betreuungsangebote**, which expands the selection by 4 buttons.
2. Afterwards the second button **stationäre Pflegeeinrichtung** should be clicked to expand the selection even further.
3. The last selection should be **Vollstationäre Pflege**.

To change the state of the searchButton to **clickable** a postal code must be entered in the searchBar, which presents proposals based on the entered postal code. One of those proposals must be selected to change the state of the searchButton, just entering the postal code is not enough.

So far I managed to click the second (2.) and third (3.) button and enter a postal code in the searchBar. Excel opens the IE window and clicks the buttons, but since the first (1.) button was not clicked beforehand it does not even show the 2. and 3. button. If i click the first button manually after executing the VBA code I can see that the 2. and 3. button are selected.

My Questions are:

1. How do I click the first button via VBA?
2. How do I submit the search for the entered postal code?
3. How do I choose one of the proposals ? (It does not even matter which one.)

I managed to click the buttons via:

```
.getElementById("ctl00_ContentPlaceHolder1_suche_btn_versorgung2").Click
```

and

```
"ctl00_ContentPlaceHolder1_suche_btn_pflegeart1" for "vollstationäre Pflege"
```

Thank you very much in advance

Comment: I spent some time over weekend writing Chrome extensions, much better way to scrub and influence a web page than driving an IE from Excel VBA.  So if you have not spent any time in VBA figuring out how to do it I suggest you begin with javascript.

Comment: Probably you will have to play with the line `<button type="button" data-tab="1"><i class="icon-care"></i><span>Pflege&shy;einrichtungen und<br/>Betreuungs&shy;angebote</span></button>
`

Comment: I´ve written a VBA macro for another website already. That website was php based, so I didnt have to deal with dopostback etc. Since I got my framework for the rest, I would prefer to do it in an Excel macro.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In the end I gave in and used [selenium basic VBA wrapper](http://florentbr.github.io/SeleniumBasic/) and here is how you do what you are after with VBA. You can use other supported browsers apart from Chrome.

**Code:**

```
Option Explicit
Public Sub test()
    Dim d As WebDriver
    Set d = New ChromeDriver 
    Const DATA_OPTION As Long = 1                '<== 1 bist Pflege­einrichtungen und Betreuungs­angebote , oder für Pflegeberatung verwenden 2: .....("button[data-tab=""2""]")
    Const LOCATION  As String = "10777 Berlin/Schöneberg" '<== Wo möchten Sie suchen?
    Const CARE_SETTING As Long = 1               '<== 1 für Ambulanter Pflegedienst. Oder: 2.Stationäre Pflegeeinrichtung ; 3.Angebote zur Unterstützung im Alltag ; 4. Häuslicher Betreuungsdienst

    With d
        .Start "Chrome"
        .Get "https://www.pflegelotse.de/(S(x2hdp4ld1i0ok4y0q2upqasz))/presentation/pl_startseite.aspx"
        .FindElementByCss("button[data-tab=""" & DATA_OPTION & """]").Click

        Application.Wait Now + TimeSerial(0, 0, 1)

        .FindElementByCss("button[data-value=""" & CARE_SETTING & """]").Click
        .FindElementById("ctl00_ContentPlaceHolder1_suche_bezirk").SendKeys LOCATION

        Application.Wait Now + TimeSerial(0, 0, 1)

        Dim keys As New keys
        .SendKeys keys.Enter

        Application.Wait Now + TimeSerial(0, 0, 1)

        .FindElementById("ctl00_ContentPlaceHolder1_suche_btn_suche").Click

        Stop

        .Quit
    End With
End Sub
```

**In action:**

[image: In action]

Comment: Thank you very much for your answer! I had to edit the Location to postalcode only and sendkey{return} to select the first proposal.

Comment: Thanks for an interesting question and sorry for my schoolboy german in the comments!